# Client specified an invalid argument. Note that this differs from failed-precondition

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I fight since a while with Firestore and its no sql system.
I try to perform the following search : Give me all Houses which match the following search address.

Firestore didn't give lot of flexibility so I want to try an other things that 'isEqualTo' because it will not be enough relevant.
I tried to do as following, but i didn't understand the error. Anyway, how can i achieve my needs ?

```dart
final String search = 'Paris';
Query<Map<String, dynamic>> query = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('houses')
    .where(
      Filter.or(
        Filter('address.city', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: search),
        Filter('address.name', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: search),
        Filter('address.department', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: search),
        Filter('address.country', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: search),
      ),
    )
    .orderBy('analytics.score', descending: true)
    .orderBy('name')
    .limit(limit);
```

Client specified an invalid argument. Note that this differs from failed-precondition. invalid-argument indicates arguments that are problematic regardless of the state of the system (e.g., an invalid field name).

My Firestore collection 'houses' contain items like :

```json
{
  "address": {
    "city": "Paris",
    "country": "France",
    "department": "75007",
    "name": "Les Invalides"
  },
  "name": "Beautiful House near the Invalides",
  "analytics": {
    "score": 10
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

You're trying to perform range conditions on multiple fields, which isn't possible on Firestore.

---

If this type of querying is required for your use-case, consider [adding an additional search engine](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) to Firestore - or using another database that is better suited to your needs